# Reading Javascript 2d String array in Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, servlets

I have a 2-dimensional array variable in my JavaScript application and I want to read that array in my Java Servlet.

```
var arry = [["property","one"],["class","name"]];
```

I am passing it to the servlet using AJAX as:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "DocumentUploader",
    data: 'array1=' + arry,
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Now I know I could loop over the array by getting it through `request.getParameter("array1")`. But the problem is that clearly I cannot access array index values as:

```
String[] arr = request.getParameter("array1");
System.out.println(arr[0][1]);
```

as the index is of type `String`. 
Please tell me if there is any way to read this type of JS array?

Comment: Try to use JSON.parse(text). Use this URL http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp

Comment: Use an http 'Post' to send  the array to the servlet. If you use Jersey 2 as the servlet combined with Jackson, you will get a Java object at server side.

Comment: ok. But the problem is that the String for the `key` in the array will also be defined dynamically by some JS code. I cannot change that code here and have to work with this only. 
The string value of key and the value associated with the key , both are being determined dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You need some tool that reads a JSON formatted `String` and converts it to Java objects.

You have [JsonObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javame/8.0/api/json/api/com/oracle/json/JsonObject.html) which comes with Java (but only JavaEE, I believe). Learn more about it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html).

And then you have two popular JSON processing libraries, [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson). Neither is best than the other, but Jackson tends to be a bit more popular because it handles automatic binding with Jersey.

Comment: ok. But the problem is that the String for the key in the array will also be defined dynamically by some JS code. I cannot change that code here and have to work with this only. The string value of key and the value associated with the key , both are being determined dynamically

Comment: That's not a problem. Did you even take a moment to read the information I gave you. Here is even more information regarding unknown format JSON processing: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel

Answer (score 0):

```js
arry = [{"property": "one"},{"class": "name"}];
```

Try to format your array with this format and then use JSON.parse on the Java side. I hope it helps